# Store switch is not working for custom categories

Tags: url-rewrite, store-view, language, redirect-url, store-switcher

I have added a categories and called that through CMS block.
When I go to that category from homepage it is going fine.
After that if I try to change the language,it is not accpeting.
say:
http://localhost/US/notebook**(normal url)**
http://localhost/US/notebook**(Even after switching it to french store)**

**Note:**I'm maintaining storeviews.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: describe some more detail, what you are looking?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya The URL switch was working fine if I disable "Add Store Code to Urls" in the backend.If I enable and try to switch the URL isn't changed.
Ex: http://localhost/US/notebook(US storeview).http://localhost/SE/notebook(SE storeview)
I want like this for notebook category.